# How can I set type aColumns when they are dynamically created DataTable JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I would like to sort my datatable but having float in the data and the columns are created dynamically make it complicated.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
                        "formatted-num-pre": function ( a ) {
                            a = (a==="-") ? 0 : a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" );
                            return parseFloat( a );
                        },
                        "formatted-num-asc": function ( a, b ) {
                            return a - b;
                        },
                        "formatted-num-desc": function ( a, b ) {
                            return b - a;
                        }
                    } );
                   
                    
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                             //   Init DataTables 
                              $('#datatable').dataTable({
                                    "bPaginate"     : false,
                                    "bJQueryUI"     : true,
                               });
                           } ); 
                 </script>
```

and here myhtml :

```
<table id="datatable" class="display">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>nom</th>
<?php for($i = 0 ; $i < $nbre ; $i++) { ?>
<th><?php echo $nom[$i]; ?></th>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php for($i = 0 ; $i < $total ; $i++) { ?>
<td><?php echo $totals_ca[$i]['nom']; ?></td>
<?php for($j = 0 ; $j < $nbre ; $j++) { ?>
<td><?php echo $totals_ca[$i][$nom[$j]]; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

to set type for static column :

```
"aoColumns": [
                                        null,
                                        null,
                                        { "sType": "formatted-num" },
                                        { "sType": "formatted-num" },
                                        { "sType": "formatted-num" },
                                        { "sType": "formatted-num" }
                                    ]
```

I want to set a number of columns of datatable with type "formatted-num". I can't use the static way because I don't know the number of columns; they are created dynamically. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to understand what you are asking. Can you rephrase?

Comment: thanks for your reply.i want to set a number of columns of datatable with type : "formatted-num" , i can't use the static way cause i don't know the number of columns , they are created dyanmicaly...